# Code help to Play Multiple Sounds (objective c) to Swift(xcode 7)

Tags: swift, function, xcode7, avaudioplayer

Trying to convert the below code `objective-c`  to `Swift`, please help me by doing so or help me with a new code to play MULTIPLE SOUNDS ***

```
- (IBAction)pushButton {    
      NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResouce:@"ring" ofType:@"mp3"];
      if(theAudio) [theAudio release];
      theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
      theAudio.delegate = self;
      [theAudio play];       
}

- (IBAction)pushButton1 {
      NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResouce:@"amaze" ofType:@"mp3"];
      if(theAudio) [theAudio release];
      theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
      theAudio.delegate = self;
      [theAudio play];
}
```

Comment: **This is not a coding service**. At least show some effort from your side!

Comment: I have been doing so from last 2 weeks (5 hours daily) just to make it play. Could do so

Comment: What did you do? Post that!

Answer (score 0):

Swift version:-

```
let path : String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ring", ofType: "mp3")!
if(theAudio){
    theAudio.release()
}
theAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path), error: &err)
audioPlayer.delegate = self
audioPlayer.play()


func pushButton1(){
    let path : String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("amaze", ofType: "mp3")!
    if(theAudio){
        theAudio.release()
    }
    theAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path), error: &err)
    audioPlayer.delegate = self
    audioPlayer.play()

}
```